# evince does not show font names in PDF files anymore

Tags: fonts, viewers, evince

First of all, this is a duplicate post of the equally named thread on [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/696444/evince-does-not-show-font-names-in-pdf-files-anymore). However since there has been zero activity and that site is arguably less helpful (especially in relation to tex.sc), I wager it warrants a new attempt here. I intend to mark the other one without an answer as quick as possible if this one gets an answer or vice versa.

Some info:

```
$ pacman -Q evince
evince 41.4-1
```

Evince does not show font names in PDF files anymore. They look alright, they seem to be embedded normally and the font tab says as much (see screenshot, although it is in my OS' language) but no font name is shown.

This problem occurs regardless of the file's age or producer/origin.

Is it maybe a LaTeX-related problem?

## Screenshot

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass[
parskip=false,
11pt,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\frenchspacing

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\pdfgentounicode=1

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{Large}
AAaaaa.\\
Some words.
\end{Large}
\end{document}
```

Comment: how is this latex related if you say it applies to all pdfs?, it is presumably a change to the pdf viewer, which isn't on topic here.

Comment: unrelated but beware using `\begin{Large}` like that: you get Large text on a normal baseline so irregular line spacing. If you do use that form, always leave a blank line before `\end{Large}`

Comment: Oh. I somehow did not come to think of that. This is a spot-on remark and rightfully voids the question's justification for existence on here. Damnit :(

Comment: About the `Large`-bit: I see! Thanks. Will try to remember that !

Comment: I saw that post on unix.stackexchange.com and tested it out on my own computer. I didn't post anything because I didn't have anything new to add, but yes, it appears to be a bug with the current version of evince. For me, in English, every font appears as "No name". But as you say, it happens regardless of how the PDF is produced, so it's not a LaTeX problem. Try asking at the [GNOME bug tracker](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is mostly neither LaTeX-based nor -related.