# Chivo font - how exactly do its weight options work?

Tags: fonts

I do not understand the usage of font weights with Chivo. I expected the entire content to be set in the weight option "light" but it only gets activated after using `\mdseries`.

=> Why is that extra command needed to have content be set as `light`? (maybe I have some big misunderstanding of that myself)

## Screenshots

**MEDIUM/no extra option**

[image]

**LIGHT**

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass[
parskip=false,
11pt,
]{scrartcl}

%\usepackage{tgheros}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[
oldstyle,
]{sourceserifpro}
\usepackage[scale=1.05]{zi4}
\usepackage[
scale=0.925,
%thin,
light,
%medium,
%familydefault=true,
]{Chivo}

\usepackage[
protrusion=true,
expansion,
babel=true,
stretch={0},
shrink={10},
]{microtype}

\frenchspacing

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\pdfgentounicode=1

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{Large}
AAaaaa.\\
Here are some words.\\\mdseries
Here are some words.
\end{Large}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [hmm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638492/evince-does-not-show-font-names-in-pdf-files-anymore#comment1591675_638492)

Comment: it's just a choice of the package author: the only thing the `light` option does in pdfex is `\def\mdseries@sf{l}` is make `\mdseries` use the light font.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, David. The "hmm" one is just a quick send-off, I suppose? :) About the second one, does that mean I have to use `\mdseries` for the whole document?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, the entire content should be typeset in light when the option is given.  Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[familydefault,light]{Chivo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\Large\noindent
AAaaaa.\\
Here are some words.\\
Here are some words.

\pagebreak \fontseries{m}\selectfont

\noindent AAaaaa.\\
Here are some words.\\
Here are some words.

\end{document}
```

which looks like this:

[image]

This is with TL2022 and chivo.sty 2022/11/15 v2.2.  Maybe you can update your installation and see if the issue remains.